# Azure DevOps Maven Docker build - can't locate target folder

Tags: docker, azure-devops, maven-3

I am new to Azure Devops and am having some difficulty building my first pipeline.  So far I have three steps that work just fine:

1. Maven build from POM, successfully packages my war file
2. Copy files to $(system.defaultworkingdirectory), copying the files I want from the target folder
3. Successful Publish of the artifact to a private Azure package repository

My 4th step runs a *DevOps Docker Task* to build a Docker image to be used to deploy the web app.  This has been a challenge because my dockerfile COPY commands are failing.  I can't locate the target folder, the one that step 3 just used to build the war file!  In an effort to locate the target folder I added this command to my dockerfile:

RUN ls -R -la /

It appears to have dumped the entire file system and the target folder is nowhere to be found in the listing.

Any thoughts regarding where I can find my target files?

I am very close to making this work the way I want. If I comment out the COPY command it builds a fundamentally empty image which my 5th step successfully pushes to my private Docker repository.  Of course the image is useless without the web app.

Any help you might offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I came up with the following azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo Starting the build
      env
      java -version
      ./mvnw clean package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -e -U
      ls -la *
    displayName: 'Build with Maven'
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: 'Build an image'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise (******)'
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"testingcontainerregistry******.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/******/resourceGroups/******/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/testingContainerRegistry******"}'
      action: 'Build an image'
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: 'Push an image'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise (******)'
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"testingcontainerregistry******.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/******/resourceGroups/******/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/testingContainerRegistry******"}'
      action: 'Push an image'
- job: test
  dependsOn: build
  condition: succeeded()
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo Performing tests
      env
      ls -la
    displayName: 'Running integration tests'
```

The testing job is not doing anything useful yet, but you can see that the Maven build and the Docker build&push are done by the same job.

Essentially I struggled with the same issue as you did. I created a GitHub ticket to make them aware of the fact that the basic concepts are not easy to understand from the current documentation: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2851